# How to disable slidingMenu for Tablet landscape mode?

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I'm developing an Android application that uses [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) with Action Bar Sherlock.

Every thing is working fine in portrait mode,But for tablet landscape mode I'm loading frames side by side , so at that time i don't want slidingMenu .

How can i disable it only in Landscape mode ?

Comment: set menudrower setTouchMode NONE\

Comment: create two layout for lanscape & protrait, also develope code for same

Comment: @ Biraj Zalavadia : ```getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_NONE);``` will work fine , And the other problem is getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);,If the user clicks on this home icon it will slide.How do i fix this ?

Comment: Why not using Android's native [Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html)?

Comment: @minipif : Does it works on version 2.3?

Comment: Yes it does, it uses [`DrawerLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html) which is in the standard support library v4.

Answer (score 2):

the best way and most dynamic is you create `bool.xml` file in   `res -> values` and `res -> values-sw720dp-land`

within the bool.xml add for `values` folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="allowSildingMenu">true</bool>
</resources>
```

and for bool.xml in `values-sw720dp-land` write:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="allowSildingMenu">false</bool>
</resources>
```

then read the values in your activity:

```
if(getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.allowSildingMenu) == true){
    //add sliding menu
} else
    //don't show it.
```

**update**

now if you don't want to show the `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` at all then within the else statement above, add false to it.

However, if you want to redirect you to previous activity you got to do some changes in `onOptionsItemSelected` function..

something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        if(getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.portrait_only) == true)
            //then open the slide menu..
        else
            super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

hope this solution works for you.

Comment: Great solution and it's working fine , And the other problem is ```getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);```,If the user clicks on this home icon it will slide.How do i fix this ?

Comment: please refer to the updated part... hope this is the right answer for you.. otherwise give me a feedback..

Comment: I have added a "false" to this code N it's working fine. ```getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad I could help :) can you mark my answer as right so people can refer to it in the future